# Possible to know which features were used as input in a keras model?

Tags: keras

I have a set of features and a keras model that was trained over a subset of these features by someone else. 
I want to evaluate this model over a new set of data, but I don't know which features were used to train it. I have originally 32 features, but only 27 were used for the training.
My question is: is it possible to somehow obtain the list of input features to the model having only the keras model itself?

Comment: No, I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras models contain only the architecture and the weights, you can know how many features were used (and you already know that), but you can't know specificly what were thoses features.
You need to find an other way to get this information !